# Push DIV down when space filled

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm trying to find out if the following is possible or not.

I have 3 chunks of html:
1. A fixed width menu button
2. A variable width title
3. A variable width list (containing buttons)

Obviously, in the illustration there is little problem, but when the design is viewed on mobile, there is a possibility that all 3 won't fit.

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to nudge the title down onto its own line once the space is filled - using CSS if possible. I've looked at a few articles on flexbox, but nothing I've found has proved or disproved whether this would work.

Anyone got an idea as to whether this is possible using flexbox, or any other method?

[image]

Comment: Flexbox can't really do that ***automatically*** as such. You could do something with a media query though. Then again...probably not.

Comment: I know I can adjust the overall width with media queries, but I'm trying to compensate for a variable width title - which media queries won't help with.

Comment: Sounds like you're after a universal solution and, other than JS, I don't think there is one....not even `flexbox`.

Answer (score 1):

I would very simply add `display:block` to the variable width title; when on a mobile device - via media queries.

I do not think it's possible to detect if the space has been filled in CSS alone.